# OpenCV 2.4.6.1: Error while grabbing frame from camera

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, osx-mountain-lion

I am using XCode (OS X Mountain Lion) with OpenCV. OpenCV is installed via homebrew (version 2.4.6.1)

My program should just access the camera.

Here is my code sofar:

```
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture cap(CV_CAP_ANY);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        std::cerr << "Webcam error. Was not able to open webcam!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    namedWindow("webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (cap.isOpened())
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            std::cerr << "Frame data error.\n";
        }

    imshow("webcam", frame);

    if(waitKey(50) >= 0)
    {
        cap.release();
        std::cout << "Webcam closed.\n";
    }
}

std::cout << "The Program has finished.";
return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the output:

> Frame data error.
>
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /tmp/default-mebu/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 261
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

I think that my program is not accessing the camera properly. It is somehow not able to get the data.

I know there have been some problems with Linux but I thought they have been fixed and I am not sure how they influenced OS X.

Does anybody know a solution to my problem?

Edit:

So I found a solution. I added a try {} catch {} for the imshow. Now my program does not exit when it hits the imshow. Instead it just throughs an error and keeps the while loop running. It misses a few frames but still gets enough to maintain a good videostream.

```
try
{
     imshow("webcam", frame);
}
catch (Exception& e)
{
    const char* err_msg = e.what();
    std::cout << "exception caught: imshow:\n" << err_msg << std::endl;
}
```

The error thrown is still the same one:

> frame data error.
>
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /tmp/default-mebu/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 261
>
> exception caught: imshow:
>   /tmp/default-mebu/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Comment: This is a known issue and apparently they're trying to fix it for the next release. For now, I'd just use 2.4.5 (if you had it with homebrew before, then you can go back to it with `brew switch opencv 2.4.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a workaround. I added a try {} catch {} for the imshow. Now my program does not exit when it hits the imshow. Instead it just throughs an error and keeps the while loop running. It misses a few frames but still gets enough to maintain a good videostream.

```
try
{
     imshow("webcam", frame);
}
catch (Exception& e)
{
    const char* err_msg = e.what();
    std::cout << "exception caught: imshow:\n" << err_msg << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoCapture cap(CV_CAP_ANY);
Sleep(1000);  // Wait for response of camera, don't forget to #include <windows.h>
```

Comment: isn't windows.h Windows OS specific? I am on OS X. Besides I have a response from the webcam, it just gives an error sometimes as if the frame contains no data.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem .You can add similar this code, maybe solve it. Because capture size cause this problem

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
```

then

```
cap.read(image);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.
Do you use
    cap.read(image)
instead of
    cap >> image
?